# Cordova File Plugin

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get the Cordova File Plugin and Cordova File Transfer to work, My code (below) should create a new folder 'Makes' and download an image into that new folder, but instead it just throws error code 1, but I can't figure out why, can someone please point me in the right direction:

```
function onAppReady(){
    if(navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide){
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    updateImages();
}


function updateImages(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fileSystemSuccess, fileSystemFail);

    function fileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
        var directoryEntry=fileSystem.root;
        directoryEntry.getDirectory("Makes", {create:true, exclusive:false}, onDirectorySuccess, onDirectoryFail);

    }
    function onDirectorySuccess(parent){
        var rootdir = fileSystem.root;
        var fp = parent.toURL(); 

        var download_link=encodeURI('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg/1122px-Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg.png');
        var fpFull=fp+'Makes/Wikipedia.png';

        filetransfer(download_link, fpFull);
    }
    function onDirectoryFail(error){alert("Unable to create new directory: "+error.code);}
    function fileSystemFail(evt){alert(evt.target.error.code);}
}

function filetransfer(download_link, fp){
    var fileTransfer=new FileTransfer();
    fileTransfer.download(download_link, fp, function(entry){
        console.log("download complete: "+entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error){
        console.log("download error: "+error.code+' - '+error.source+' - '+error.target);
    });
}

document.addEventListener("app.Ready", onAppReady, false);
```

Comment: What is that error ?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions

Comment: I get error code 1 which is 'FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR' but I can't see what's wrong.